# How to create dynamic database table in SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am  trying to create one application to store information in sq-lite table.

But i want to take table information from user like table name, columns name, and number of columns, also user can edit that by table name, delete column add new column.
how can i do it.

[image]

i add example screen for table filed

Comment: So what's the problem? Take the information entered by the user to assemble your `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: what problem u are facing it is simple

Answer (score 0):

Android allows you to execute arbitrary SQL strings. Construct a SQL strings from your UI and then input the string into a command similar to `db.execute(string)`.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#execute())